Celery exiting with code 0 after starting workers
Guys, please help me find where the problem can be? Workers are starting fine and then celery just dies without a reason and even exit code 0
This is celery part in docker-compose.yml
celery:
  build:
    context: ./backend
    dockerfile: ./celeryDockerfile
  container_name: celery
  env_file: .env
  healthcheck:
    test: celery -b amqp://${RABBITMQ_USER}:${RABBITMQ_PASS}@rabbit status || exit 1
    interval: 5s
    timeout: 10s
    retries: 3
  entrypoint: [ "/app/celery-entrypoint.sh" ]
  command: celery multi start 2 --logfile=logs/celery.log -l INFO
  depends_on:
    backend:
      condition: service_healthy
    rabbit:
      condition: service_healthy


And this is log output
celery     | celery started
celery     | celery multi v5.4.0 (opalescent)
celery     | > Starting nodes...
celery     |    > celery1@3e42fac37fa0: OK
celery     |    > celery2@3e42fac37fa0: OK
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
 Container frontend  Stopping
 Container frontend  Stopped
 Container backend  Stopping
 Container backend  Stopped
 Container gateway  Stopping
 Container gateway  Stopped
 Container dashboard  Stopping
 Container dashboard  Stopped
 Container celery  Stopping
 Container celery  Stopped
 Container rabbit  Stopping
 Container rabbit  Stopped
 Container db  Stopping
 Container db  Stopped
 Container files  Stopping
 Container files  Stopped
dependency failed to start: container celery exited (0)

Ignore the entrypoint part there is only echo celery started inside

Turns out celery multi runs and then exits so i found this gist to help with my problem.
To summarize what does code from the gist do:

Start the workers with celery multi start and related parameters
Start trapping signals using trap to capture TERM and INT signals
Start tail -f for logs to redirect them into console
Capture tail -f's PID
wait "$child" will allowing to redirect logs indefinitely and capture any signal i.e TERM
There is a teardown function to kill celery workers with celery multi stop and kill tail -f process with it's PID


Real question is - do you really want to use celery multi? It actually starts TWO Celery workers in your case. Each of them will spawn N number of worker processes, where N is number of cores.
